# Some question of hartshorne book (V.2.2)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow C$ be a ruled surface with a section $\sigma : C \rightarrow X$ and let $D=\sigma(C)$ be a divisor on $X$
Let $\mathcal{F}= \pi_*\mathcal{L}(D)$ Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $2$ and $\pi^*\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(D)$ is surjective. So there is a morphsim $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$ over $C$ such that $g^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}(1) \cong \mathcal{L}(D)$. Since $D$ on fibre has degree $1$ and any fibre is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, $D$ is very ample on each fibre.

In proof of Harhshorne (V.2.2), By above facts, $g$ is an isomorphism on each fibre and so $g$ is isomorphism.. But I don't understand this...

Comment: Which part don't you understand: why $g$ is an iso on each fibre, or why it is a global iso?

Comment: yes you're alright

Comment: Dear Sang Cheol Lee, I still don't understand which part you don't understand.

Comment: anyway, thank your kindness^^